# Azure AD Not Authenticating in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to get Azure AD working in an existing application. I've followed the instructions and looked at the sample code from Microsoft's site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) with no luck. The sample code is using .NET Core 2.1. I can get it to work with .NET Core 2.1 but 3.1 is throwing a fit for a couple reasons.

1. Compared to sample code one needs to set the EnableEndpointRouting to false.
2. Compared to sample code I tried removing the set compatibilityversion on AddMvc and also tried using it as being set to 3.0.

When I run it in .NET Core 3.1 all it does is load the page and never calls out/perform the authentication and is behaving as if there is not Authorize tag on the controller.

I have an Authorize tag on the class level in controller.

Startup.cs:

```
...
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });
```

Then down below in the Configure function:

```
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Then in my appsettings.json I have:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "guid",
    "ClientId": "guid",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
...
```

My question is why is it treating the requests as if their is no authentication? I have also tried using the UseAuthorization below the UseAuthentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to configure Azure AD for .net core 3.1 web app, please refer to the following steps

1. [Register Azure AD web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app)
2. Configure application

   a. Install SDK `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`

```
     <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="3.1.1" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

b. Update appsettings.json

```
      "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "guid",
    "ClientId": "guid",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
...
```

c. Update startup.cs

- add the following code in `ConfigureServices` function

  ```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
      {

          options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
          options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;

      });
      services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

      services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
      {
          options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
          options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
      });
      services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
      {
          var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .Build();
          options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
      });
      services.AddRazorPages();
  }
  ```
- Add the following code in `Configure` Function

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
        ...
         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseCookiePolicy();
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseAuthorization();

         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
             endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         });
     }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg)

Comment: Got it working with this answer, in addition I needed to switch the authentication settings to "Enable Anonymous Authentication" as checked and "Enable Windows Authentication" as unchecked. This is under Project -> Properties -> Debug.

Comment: My specific issue was setting the cookie policy `MinimumSameSitePolicy` to `Lax`. After changing to `Unspecified` everything worked as expected...

Comment: but how to do it in 5.0 ?